# Why do questions that have been closed still have a 'flag' option?

Tags: discussion

For example see this question - [What is new in ASP.NET MVC 5.1 apart from those mentioned in Release Notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343812/what-is-new-in-asp-net-mvc-5-1-apart-from-those-mentioned-in-release-notes)

This has been closed but still I can see a 'flag' question option, what is this for ?

Comment: To flag a post for moderator attention? Note: that post was closed by *community members*, not the moderators.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that once a question has been closed it can edited which is supposed to be so it can be improved, but instead a person could insert an offensive rant about it getting closed for example.

Comment: You can even flag deleted posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag option is there to flag the post for moderator attention. Use this option if you need a moderator to handle things the community cannot (such as notifying the mods of suspicious behavior, ask for specific help with that post only a moderator can provide, etc.)

Note that the post was closed *by community members* (who voted to close the post). Anyone with the [close vote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) can cast such votes. Flagging to close is only needed when you don't yet reach that privilege, and flagging to close is not the only flag option you have.

You can also still flag the post as offensive or spam, in case the post was edited to contain something that needs a harsher response than closing.

Comment: @Toon: *almost*. Two Dutch guys trying to spell English words, indeed..

Comment: Tunnel vision, only saw the first e/i ;-).

Comment: Certainly not for flagging to tell us the close reason that was used to close the question. (Seriously. We get those flags on a regular basis.)

Answer (score 7):

All the flagging reasons still apply, even though it is closed.

- **it is spam** - Well, it could still be spam even if it's closed.
- **it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech** - This could still be true of a closed question. Or it could've been edited by the asker as a sort of 'revenge' post, calling everying fasists for closing it or something similar
- **other (needs ♦ moderator attention)** - Useful if it's been edited and suitable for reopening (among many other reasons)

Flagging is used for more than just closing posts. So those reasons still apply even if it is already closed.

Answer (score 1):

Check what flags are available: spam, offensive and moderator attention. All those are still applicable for closed questions. The first two because people who closed the question originally might have not considered it spam/offensive but you may believe it is. Moderator attention flag really needs to be available on every posts - as that's the basic mechanism to notify mods.

Comment: Fun fact: If a post is deleted between page load and you clicking "flag", the "other" option is still available - despite the post being deleted.